# How to add union members in an inherited class/struct

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, struct, unions

```
struct Foo 
{
    union {
        struct { int a, b; };
        int index[2];
    };
};

struct Bar : public Foo 
{
    union {
        // Foo members
        struct { int barA, barB; };
    };

};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    // I want it so that
    &b.a == &b.barA;
    // in the same way that
    &f.a == &f.index[0];
}
```

is there any way to make it so that Bar's members are 'union-ized' with its parent class?

Thanks so much, any help is much appreciated

*edit:*
Here is the use case as requested:

```
struct Vec2
{
    union {
        float index[2]; 
        struct { float x, y; };
    };

    Vec2(float xVal, float yVal)
        : x(xVal), y(yVal)
    {   
    }

    ~Vec2() {}

    Vec2 & add(const Vec2 & b) { /* implimentation */ }
    Vec2 & sub(const Vec2 & b) { /* implimentation */ }

};

struct ComplexNumber : public Vec2
{
    union {
        // Vec2 members
        struct { float real, imag; };
    };

    ComplexNumber(float realPart, float imagPart)
        : real(realPart), imag(imagPart)
    {
    }

    ComplexNumber & mul(const ComplexNumber & b) { /* implimentation */ }
    ComplexNumber & div(const ComplexNumber & b) { /* implimentation */ }
};

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber a(5, 2);
    ComplexNumber b(7, 8);
}
```

I would like to be able to not only address a and b's Vec2 members, 
but also use the functions declared in Vec2 or possibly even add 
ComplexNumbers and Vec2s interchangably.

Comment: Does Bar have to inherit (is-a) from Foo, or can it contain (has-a) Foo?

Comment: `struct { int a, b; };` is an anonymous struct member. Anonymous structs are not allowed in C++.

Comment: This is a neat question. I can see many reasons why it should be disallowed, derived class can't be able to change the size of the base class, but if the size doesn't change, is there enough of a use-case to inject an exception that allows it into the Standard?

Comment: Suggestion: Gabe, add your use case, if this isn't just for academic purposes, to the question. Someone can probably give you a work-around or alternative.

Comment: in what way is "struct {int a, b;}" disallowed? I'm compiling with g++ with all warnings enabled and get none.

Comment: The reason why Bar inherits Foo is because I would like Foo to also inherit all of Foo's member functions.

Comment: Random find: https://gist.github.com/sjolsen/6323929

Comment: @GabeRundlett g++ allows some non standard behaviour with extensions. Pretty much all compilers do, so if you want portable code you have to watch out. In this case I suspect it's done to maintain closer compatibility with C, which does allow anonymous structs.

Comment: My code at the moment just has 'ComplexNumber' as a rewrite of Vec2 with the necessary 'add' and 'sub' methods for complex numbers / vec2s but I would like to just need to pass a Vec2 pointer so that I don't need a function for both adding a complex number and adding a Vec2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unions in `Foo` and in `Bar` are an anonymous ones.  This is syntactic sugar that allows to access their members as if they were in the enclosing class:

> **[class.union.anon]/1:**
>   For the purpose of name lookup, after the anonymous union definition, the members  of the anonymous union are considered to have been defined in the scope in which  the anonymous union is declared.

But this is only a facilitation of member access.  The anonymous union object is not merged in its enclosing class.  As a consequence, in `Bar` there are two different unions (with objects at different addresses). These cannot be unionized/merged.

By the way, the standard explicitly forbids union to inherit in any ways:

> **[class.union]/3:**
>   A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class.

There is no way to do what you intend to do.

Looking at your specific case,  the merged union that you would like to establish in the derived class seems to have a one to one relation with the parts of the base class.  In view of these circumstances, you could as a **workaround** use some references to refer to the same member:

```
struct ComplexNumber : public Vec2
{
    float &real=x, &imag=y;

    ComplexNumber(float realPart, float imagPart) : Vec2 (realPart, imagPart)
    {
    }
    ...
 };
```

Of course, you'd need to implement the rule of 3, in order to avoid any issue (e.g. reference pointing to the wrong object, in case a copy constructor or an assignment is done).

Now the real question is whether or not a complex is a Vec2.  Personally, I'd rather go to a clearer approach, making the complex be and independent class and have a Vec2 member.  In this case,  the complex would redefine the Vec2 operations and forward the member functions to the Vec2 member.

Comment: Clear explanation and even better recommendation.